# Expressing using properties of vectors

Tags: vectors

It is given in question that $x+a=(a.x)b$ and it is stated that a,b and x are vectors.It is also stated that $a.b$ not equal to $1$.The question ask to express $x$ in term $a$ and $b$,how do you this?

Comment: This notation is unclear. What is $ab$ when they are both vectors? What is $a.b$?

Comment: I think that $( a.b)$ denotes the scalar product of two real vectors $a,b$ in an euclidean space.

Comment: What work have you done on this problem? For example, can you show us a diagram that shows $a,b,$ and $x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

taking the dot product with $\underline{a}$ we have

$$\underline{x}\cdot\underline{a}+\underline{a}\cdot\underline{a}=(\underline{a}\cdot\underline{x})\underline{b}\cdot\underline{a}$$
Rearranging, noting that $\underline{a}\cdot\underline{a}=a^2$ and that $\underline{x}\cdot\underline{a}=\underline{a}\cdot\underline{x}$, we have
$$\underline{a}\cdot\underline{x}=\frac{a^2}{\underline{b}\cdot\underline{a}-1}$$
Note that the denominator is not zero.
Hence, $$\underline{x}=\underline{b}\frac{a^2}{\underline{b}\cdot\underline{a}-1}-\underline{a}$$

Comment: I am sorry,can you clarify on the first part where you take the dot product a because i don't seem to get it on that part.

Comment: I have added to my answer for further clarification. I hope this helps.