# Vector. Properties

Tags: vectors

It is given in a question that $\vec x+\vec a=(\vec a\cdot \vec x)\vec b$ and it is stated that $\vec a$, $\vec b$ and $\vec x$ are vectors.

It is also stated that $\vec a\cdot \vec b\ne 1$.

The question asks to express $\vec x$ in term $\vec a$ and $\vec b$.

How do you this?

Comment: just the same question was https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668721/expressing-using-properties-of-vectors

Comment: Don't know if this is really the root of your problem, but do you understand $(\vec a\cdot \vec x)\vec b$?

Comment: I do not quite understand. Look at solution can you please explain to me

Comment: No, I can't. As long as I don't know what you are missing, I could write megabytes of explanations ... . $(\vec a\cdot \vec x)\vec b$ ... tell me what you think it is! What is $(\vec a\cdot \vec x)$? Is it a vector? A scalar? A matrix?

Comment: Vector , right. I sure that

Comment: OK, so what is $(\vec a\cdot \vec x)$?

Comment: Dot product vector

Comment: OK, so a dot product of vectors is a) scalar b) vector c) matrix?

Comment: Vector . I am sure

Comment: Gotcha! It's a scalar. Now go over the problem again with this in mind. If it helps, give a name to $(\vec a\cdot \vec x)$.

Comment: Scalar dot product

Comment: So now you know $\vec a\cdot\vec x$ is a scalar, rewrite $\vec x+\vec a=(\vec a\cdot \vec x)\vec b$ as $\vec x+\vec a=\xi\vec b$ with $\xi=\vec a\cdot\vec x$. Now look a the answer given. Does it make more sens to you now?

Comment: Yes . It makes sense now. But I so confused on the second step

Comment: Rewrite with $\alpha:= \vec a\cdot\vec a$ and $\beta:=\vec a\cdot\vec b$. Now the first expression is a simple equation of scalars, no magic, no vectors involved.

Comment: Ok then. What should I do

Comment: Hm, either you should take a break and look at it again when the new information has settled in, or you should show me what you get from the rewriting.

Comment: Again. Why alpha=a.a while Beta equal a.b. how do you get that

Comment: Simply calling an expression by a new, arbitrarily given new name. Kind of an abbreviation.

Comment: It hides away all the vectors so one can do with simple algebra.

Comment: Hello???. Do u know what i mean . See the second step . How did Dr.Mv get that?It keeps me dizzy

Comment: Hello!!! ! What did u try?

Comment: At the answer. I mean. See the second step . I dont understand

Comment: Sure you don't understand the second if you don't understand the first. What do you get when you apply my suggested rewriting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Form the inner product of both sides of the equation with $\vec a$.

**SPOILER ALERT:**  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution

> Let $$\vec x=(\vec a\cdot \vec x)\vec b-\vec a \tag 1$$  Then, forming the inner product of both sides of the equation with $\vec a$ yields$$\vec a\cdot \vec x=(\vec a\cdot \vec x)(\vec a\cdot \vec b)-(\vec a\cdot \vec a) \tag 2$$Solving $(2)$ for $\vec a\cdot \vec x$, we find that $$\vec a\cdot \vec x=\frac{\vec a\cdot \vec a}{\vec a\cdot \vec b-1} \tag 3$$Substituting $(3)$ back into the original equation $(1)$ yields $$\vec x =(-1)\vec a+\left(\frac{\vec a\cdot \vec a}{\vec a\cdot \vec b-1}\right)\vec b$$

Comment: How to form the inner product. Dr.MV

Comment: How do you form the second step

Comment: Again . Please show me more detail step. It can help me understand more

Comment: Luna.  I added a "Spoiler Alert" section that shows the development.   What is it specifically that you don't understand?

Comment: I cannot understand the second and third step . How do you arrange the third step

Comment: Please I really ur help right now.huhuhu

Comment: Luna.   The second step simply solves the previous equation for $\vec a\cdot \vec x$.  The third and final step uses that result and substitutes it back into the first equation.

Comment: The problem is I do not know to solve the second step .Please teach me

Comment: @luna What do you get when you apply my suggested rewriting?

Comment: If we have $y=Cy +D$, then $y=\frac{D}{1-C}$.  Now, let $y=\vec a\cdot \vec x$, $C=\vec a\cdot \vec b$, and $D=-\vec a\cdot \vec a$.

Comment: Yeah Dr. MV that the answer I want. Else, what the question what to tell us about a.b /= 1

Comment: @luna just for my understanding for how to handle such cases in the future, can you please tell me what point sparked your understanding?

Comment: @luna: you have asked the very same question again here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1669062/290307